# Can we set the value of "description" meta attribute dynamically?

Tags: html, jsf

Can we have something like following in case of HTML + JSF

```
<meta  name="description" content="#{MyBean.attr}"/>
```

i.e. can we set the value of "description" meta attribute dynmically?

Comment: that is   = `<meta  name="description" content="#{MyBean.attr}"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work when you're using JSF with Facelets as view technology. However, since you're asking this question it seems that you're using legacy JSP as view technology wherein unified EL (those `#{}` things) in template text isn't supported. You need to use JSF `h:outputText` component then to print the bean property.

```
<meta name="description" content="<h:outputText value="#{MyBean.attr}" />" />
```

Ugly, yes, but that's the payoff of sticking to a legacy view technology which isn't originally designed with JSF in mind ;) If you're curious about Facelets, have a look at its [docbook](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html). It's by the way the default view technology in JSF 2.0 and newer.